# Issue with spring boot post call. Unable to call controller from client side

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am bit new to spring boot and I have developed the following logic:

Here is my requirement. Just I wanted to upload images to tomcat server for that I have tried this logic with spring boot

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new File(UploadController.uploadDir).mkdirs();
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
public class UploadController() {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public String get(Model model) {
    return "abc";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadFiles(@RequestParam("uploadedFiles") MultipartFile[] uploadedFiles) throws IOException {
        for(MultipartFile f : uploadedFiles) {
            File file = new File(uploadDir + f.getOriginalFilename());
            f.transferTo(file);
        }

        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Here, get request is working fine. Here is the code for get

```
public static String get() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/test");
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
            return br.readLine();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (null != conn) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            if (null != br) {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am not sure how can I call post method. I tried with same logic with POST as request type. BUt not able to upload the images. Can anyone post me the code for upload from client side?

Answer (score 0):

With JSP and Javascript, code will look like below:

JSP code:

```
<input name="media[]" type="file" id="xmlTemplate" multiple>
```

Javascript code:

```
var data = new FormData();     
jQuery.each($('input[name^="media"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append("uploadedFiles", file);
});

var json = '{' + .... + ']}';//Some JSON I was also passing alongwith files

data.append('estimateInfo', new Blob([json], {
                        type: "application/json"
                    }));

$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: 'createEstimates',
        success: function(result) {

        },
        error: function(result) {

        }
      });
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEstimates", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
    @ResponseBody
    public EstimateResponse createEstimates(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestPart("estimateInfo") EstimateInfo estimateInfo, @RequestPart("uploadedFiles") MultipartFile... files) {
}
```

If you want to send from Java client, then you can refer to [Upload Files Programmatically](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically)